# How to deal with null date fields in Data Studio?

Tags: datetime, looker-studio

We have a custom service that pulls data from a third party into Google Sheets. One of these fields is a date field, but not all records have a value, so Data Studio sees it as a Text field and won't let me manually change it to a Date or DateTime field.

I've created a calculated field to act as a replacement. I've tried several methods to convert the value to a Date value:

```
CAST(MyDate AS DATE)

CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(MyDate, 1, 4), SUBSTR(MyDate, 6, 2), SUBSTR(MyDate, 9, 2)) AS DATE)

IF(MyDate != "", CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(MyDate, 1, 4), SUBSTR(MyDate, 6, 2), SUBSTR(MyDate, 9, 2)) AS DATE), NULL)
```

and some variations thereof. However, even though Data Studio recognizes it as a valid formula, it shows NULL for every record regardless of the base value.

I need this field for the chart date range. I added a filter to exclude `Is Null`, but then the chart is empty. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse text to a date, please use

```
PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", date_text)
```

If it is not possible to parse it, the field will be null.

Comment: I ended up having to use `PARSE_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E3SZ", MyDate)` but this pointed me in the right direction.